# Money Count Up with Javascript using Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I have a counter with a start date and no end date. Basically, every second that passes after the start date it counts up $41.70/second. This continues indefinitely.

I have built the functionality. The only part I am struggling with is that I want it to count up like a ticker starting from the cents.
(ex. 1,200.98 -> 1,200.99 -> 1,201.00 and etc.)

**Here is an example of the Count Up feature I would like to adapt. Though I wouldn't be using the "data-count" attribute like they do in example.**

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  
  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },

  {

    duration: 8000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }

  });  
  
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="2200">0</div>
```

**Here is my code:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
 startDate("May 01, 2017 00:00:00 EST");
};

function startDate(x) {
 rightNow = new Date();
 x = new Date(x);
 difference = rightNow - x;
 amtPerSecond = (41.70 * (difference / 1000)).formatMoney(2);
 $("#perSecond").text("$ " + amtPerSecond);
 clearTimeout(startDate.to);
 startDate.to = setTimeout(function() {
  startDate(x);
 }, 1000);
}


// Plug-in to combact safari's incompatibility with .toLocaleString() 
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t) {
 var n = this,
  c = isNaN((c = Math.abs(c))) ? 2 : c,
  d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
  t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
  s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
  i = String(parseInt((n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c)))),
  j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
 return (
  s +
  (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") +
  i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) +
  (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "")
 );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="perSecond"></div>
```

Any help in tackling that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a rolling counter working from your example. The key is to pass the current value of the amount and the expected value into an `animateCount` function. Then in this function, before calling `animate` on the `perSecond` element, you first give it a custom property, I called it `counter`, and set its value to the current amount value. Then in the animate function you are telling it to update this property up to the expected next value during the defined duration.

After providing the duration and the type of animation, you define the `step` function (as you see in the example you provided). This is called for every step  of the animation and is therefore ideal to update the text in a rolling manner. In this function you set the text value of the element, which is just the counter property formatted with your `formatMoney` function.

Now all you have to do is call this animate function every time the `startDate` is called. Note that you do not set the text value of the `perSecond` directly here, the animate function takes care of it. Additionally the duration of the animation and the length of the timeout should be the same value to make it have a seamless counter.

I've added a working code to a jsfiddle, take a look:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdr4fzg3/)**

Comment: That you so much for the detailed explanation Sasang. This is perfect!